# How to Change my URL To Some Other Domain URL

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, cross-domain

We have two websites
1)a.com
2)b.com

a.com is the new website and b.com is the old one. In future a.com will replace the b.com. For now whatever functionality is not present in a.com we are directing users to b.com website. user is sharing sessions on these two websites for to and fro traffic. Now we don't want user to see the b.com anymore because a.com website is the future. So Customer should always see a.com in the url whether they are navigating on b.com to access any page.
What will be the best way to achieve this? Can I change the URL, when my customers are on b.com to a.com, just for the display purpose? In this case they will know that they are on a.com but actually they are on b.com.

Please let me know if I made spaghetti while explaining to you the scenario?

Comment: [This](http://html5demos.com/history) allows you to alter the url with some AJAX and js. Could possibly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One general idea is to capture on BeginRequest the url, and redirect if necessary, here is an example:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

    if (Request.RawUrl.StartsWith("http://b.com"))
    {
        app.Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace("http://b.com", "http://a.com"), true);            
        return;
    }       
}
```

Comment: why it is giving me this error? 'System.Web.HttpApplication' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpApplication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Since I suppose you "own" both domains, a simple approach would be to just change the DNS settings so b.com points to a.com 
By doing this, everyone visiting b.com will see the same they'd see on a.com

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is redirect users from site b.com to site a.com but if the two sites are different then that won't help.